# Magento 2 pub/static files being deleted repeatedly. HELP!

Tags: magento2

For some reason, when certain changes are applied via backend, ALL files in pub/static are deleted - over and over again. I restore them, make a few changes - puff, they're gone.

Can someone help? What is going on?

Thanks!